# How to pass data table to modal in Django?

Tags: python, jquery, django

My teacher gave me schoolwork on how to pass data table to modal class in Django.
I just want to display the profile click in table to modal. Any help can make me grateful thanks.I'm just a newbie here and since it was almost 2 weeks I've been starting learning django Below is my currently code and it's not working.

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpTqg.jpg) | [modal after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3P0B.jpg)

> accounts.html

```
<table style="width: 100%;" id="example" class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Action</th>
                            <th>Firstname</th>
                            <th>Lastname</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Username</th>
                         
                            <th>Date joined</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                    {% for user_information in user_information %}
                        <tr>
                            <td><a class="btn btn-info" class="open-modal"  onClick = "exampleModal({{ user_information.first_name }},{{ user_information.last_name }})">Edit</a></td>
                            <td>{{user_information.first_name}}</td>
                            <td>{{user_information.last_name}}</td>
                            <td>{{user_information.email}}</td>
                            <td>{{user_information.username}}</td>
                            <td>{{user_information.date_joined}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>  
                </table>
                
                  <div id="modal-div">
                    <p id="firstNameValueId">Some text in the Modal..</p>
                    <p id="secondNameValueId">Some text in the Modal..</p>
                 </div>
```

> mymodal

```
<div id="modal-div">
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Personal Information</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
            
                    <form action="#" method="post">
                        <label for="firstname">  <p id="firstNameValueId">Some text in the Modal..</p></label>
                        <div>
                            <input type="text" class="custom-input1 form-control " id="firstNameValueId" name="firstname" placeholder="First name" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="lastname">Last name</label>
                        <div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="secondNameValueId" name="lastname" placeholder="Last name" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

> js

```
script type="text/javascript">

        function exampleModal(firstName,lastName){
            document.getElementById('firstNameValueId').innerHTML = firstName
            document.getElementById('secondNameValueId').innerHTML = lastName
            $("#modal-div").modal();
        }
    </script>
```

> Mywholecode

```
{% extends 'navigation.html' %}
{% block content %}  

 <script> 

    function exampleModal(firstName,lastName){
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            document.getElementById('firstNameValueId').innerHTML = firstName
            document.getElementById('secondNameValueId').innerHTML = lastName
            $("#exampleModal").modal();
        });
    }

</script>



    <div class="tabs-animation">
        <div class="card mb-3">
            <div class="card-header-tab card-header">
                <div class="card-header-title font-size-lg text-capitalize font-weight-normal"><i
                        class="header-icon lnr-laptop-phone mr-3 text-muted opacity-6"> </i>Accounts Information
                </div>
                <div class="btn-actions-pane-right actions-icon-btn">
                    <div class="btn-group dropdown">
                        <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"
                            class="btn-icon btn-icon-only btn btn-link">
                            <i class="pe-7s-menu btn-icon-wrapper"></i>
                        </button>
                        <div tabindex="-1" role="menu" aria-hidden="true" class="dropdown-menu-right rm-pointers dropdown-menu-shadow dropdown-menu-hover-link dropdown-menu">
                            <h6 tabindex="-1" class="dropdown-header">Header</h6>
                            <button type="button" tabindex="0" class="dropdown-item">
                                <i class="dropdown-icon lnr-inbox"> </i><span>Menus</span>
                            </button>
                            <button type="button" tabindex="0" class="dropdown-item">
                                <i class="dropdown-icon lnr-file-empty"> </i><span>Settings</span>
                            </button>
                            <button type="button" tabindex="0" class="dropdown-item">
                                <i class="dropdown-icon lnr-book"> </i><span>Actions</span>
                            </button>
                            <div tabindex="-1" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <div class="p-3 text-right">
                                <button class="mr-2 btn-shadow btn-sm btn btn-link">View Details</button>
                                <button class="mr-2 btn-shadow btn-sm btn btn-primary">Action</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                 <table style="width: 100%;" id="example" class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Action</th>
                            <th>Firstname</th>
                            <th>Lastname</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Username</th>
                         
                            <th>Date joined</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                    {% for user_information in user_information %}
                        <tr>
                            <td><a class="btn btn-info"   onClick = "exampleModal('{{user_information.first_name}}','{{user_information.last_name}}')">Edit</a></td>
                            <td>{{user_information.first_name}}</td>
                            <td>{{user_information.last_name}}</td>
                            <td>{{user_information.email}}</td>
                            <td>{{user_information.username}}</td>
                            <td>{{user_information.date_joined}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>  
                </table>
                
                 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}


<div id="modal-div">
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Personal Information</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
            
                    <form action="#" method="post">
                        <label for="firstname">  <p id="firstNameValueId">Some text in the Modal..</p></label>
                        <div>
                            <input type="text" class="custom-input1 form-control " id="firstNameValueId" name="firstname" placeholder="First name" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="lastname">Last name</label>
                        <div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="secondNameValueId" name="lastname" placeholder="Last name" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is with the use of the `.html` method in your `<script>` section.

The `.html` method function does:

> Gets the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched elements.

So as you can see that you are trying to paste `HTML` contents with your data which has no effect. All you need to do is to use the `.innerHTML` attribute to apply the text of an element in the modal, e.g.

```
document.getElementById('<Element>').innerHTML = data.<fieldValue>;
```

**Update** - based on your new request

As said in the comments you dont have to make a request to the `back-end` to fetch data that you already have available. You can simply pass those values to javaScript function which can then update and open the modal.

**Firstly**, change this:

```
<div id="modal-div">
   <p id="firstNameValueId">Some text in the Modal..</p>
   <p id="secondNameValueId">Some text in the Modal..</p>
</div>
```

And

```
<td><a class="btn btn-info" class="open-modal"  onClick = "showValuesInModal('{{ user_information.first_name }}','{{ user_information.last_name }}')">Edit</a></td>
```

**Secondly**, remove the jQuery function and create a simple JavaScript function that will accept the values

```
<script>

function showValuesInModal(firstName,lastName){
    document.getElementById('firstNameValueId').innerHTML = firstName
    document.getElementById('secondNameValueId').innerHTML = lastName
    $("#modal-div").modal();
}
<script>
```

Now this will set the values in the `p` tag and will open the modal as required.

**Also note that there are far better and efficient approaches to this, mainly using Bootstrap and jQuery but given your skills and experience this may prove difficult. So I have provided you with something that will work but in no-way elegant.**

Comment: This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59625095/why-bootstrap4-modal-doesnt-show-data-in-my-django-template) may also help. If the answer solves your problem feel free to accept the answer by clicking the tick sign

Comment: thanks for your response where does the gg comes from? document.getElementById('gg').innerHTML = data.galeriaID;

Comment: if you are referring to the example, it's just a placeholder - it doesn't exist, but any HTML element within the modal can be replaced with that.

Comment: Actually my problem is I don't know how to pass data from my data table into modal and retrieve all data in database to modal, it seems my question been change, please help me

Comment: Im referring to this topic but I it did not work for me [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45310054/passing-data-form-datatable-to-modal-django)  @AzyCrw4282

Comment: Thank you, you're the only one replied to my questions. I've been searching almost 2 weeks,Im stuck with this module :(

Comment: Quoting this from above `data table into modal and retrieve all data in database to modal`. What information do you intend to display in the `modal`? if it's just the first name and last name then you don't have to make a request to `views.py`, you can simply pass the field values to be displayed in the modal.

Comment: @D-jason see my updated answer. I hope it solves your problem..

Comment: @ AzyCrw4282 Thank you for your response I really appreciate it, but i looks like there's  error on this line https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBq8J.jpg

Comment: I updated my current code above but I think it doesn't recognized the script js result is uncaught referrence error https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRLUF.png

Comment: It still it has an issue. I think there's problem in script ? please help https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSbeS.jpg . I edited my current code above  @AzyCrw4282

Comment: Are your tags in modal named as `firstNameValueId` and `secondNameValueId`? It has to be the id of the tags

Comment: Yes this is how it looks likes,https://i.stack.imgur.com/SW7Ap.jpg. I also add modal code above

Comment: Thanks for your response ,Is there any I missed? @AzyCrw4282

Comment: Is your script tag within an HTML file? The problem could be that you are trying to manipulate an element before its present in the DOM. You need to use [this](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) jquery property to ensure everything is applied in the dom and place the function calls within it. And check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20693718/error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-innerhtml-of-null)

Comment: Yes my script is within my HTML file ,I add my entire code above to see what the problem, I updated the script in mywholecode above but it seems not working, please check this out .I appreciate your effort thank you very much

Comment: I am afraid, i can't tell what's going wrong. All looks fine to me. I am also not using a system in which I can run and debug this so you are really on your own to look into the error and figure out where it could be going wrong.

Comment: The best advice I can tell you is to look into `walkthrough tutorials ` covering the same problem and that should give you ways in which you can incorporate `modal` logic into this.

Comment: Same for me I can't tell where is the problem but I think the problem is the position of the script even I just tried the alert but nothing display. I'm using extend in that html file and the script is below the extend but the result is the same @AzyCrw4282